# Flutter white screen in debug mode

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am pretty new to app development and currently building an application using flutter and firebase. When running the app from vscode on a web server, the page opens up but all that is there is a white screen. I have shared a screenshot of where the code stops in debug mode and what the debug console displays.

I have tried running it in release mode and it works fine.

Here is the code it stalls at, in particular the "completer.complete();" line

```
web.document.head!.appendChild(script);

Completer completer = Completer();

globalContext.callMethod(
  'ff_trigger_$windowVar'.toJS,
  (JSAny module) {
    globalContext[windowVar] = module;
    globalContext.delete('ff_trigger_$windowVar'.toJS);
    completer.complete();
  }.toJS,
);

await completer.future;
```

And here is the debug console at the time:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
This app is linked to the debug service: 
 ws://127.0.0.1:62034/KUdeZtTLb54=/ws
 Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62034/KUdeZtTLb54=/ws
 Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:62034/KUdeZtTLb54=/ws
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Just updated it, thank you

Comment: Please remove the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Running flutter clean solved this issue for me.